# Selenide Remote browser config for Gradle Test

Tags: gradle, selenide, selenoid, selenium-remotedriver

I am preparing my project to be able to start under Bitbucket + Jenkins.
I need to run Selenide solution with Remote Selenium Server (like Selenoid)

If I do a basic setup of the Configuration in TestBase Class like:

```
    public void beforeTest(){    
        Configuration.remote = "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub";     
    }
```

It is working but only when running from IntelliJ IDEA, not from the console.

If I run `Gradle test` it is starting locally - not on a grid/selenoid.

I tried to add the property to the `gradle.properties` file like:
`systemProp.selenide.remote=http://localhost:4444/wd/hub`
but this is not working as well.

The same with build.gradle file. I tried many options:

```
systemProperty("selenide.remote", "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub")
systemProperties['selenide.remote'] = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'
System.setProperty("selenide.remote", "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub")
```

All of these are not working for me.

I used property added to Gradle from the console:

`gradle clean test -Dselenide.remote=http://localhost:4444/wd/hub`

Which is still not working as expected... :(

Do you have any ideas about what can be wrong?
What should be a proper solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the working solution is:

```
systemProperty("selenide.remote", "http://0.0.0.0:4444/wd/hub")
```

There was probably an additional issue with IntelliJ IDEA. After few restarts + Invalidate/Restart option, this is working properly.